# Tomcat application: Frequent OutOfMemory PermGen exception while image uploads

Tags: tomcat, permgen

I have a tomcat 6 application which I have set parameters of -Xms512m -Xmx1024m. I thought 1 GB of memory in a 4 GB RAM would be enough, but that is not the case. On application stop/start multiple times (from tomcat manager) and also on image uploads (sometimes) I run into the OutOfMemory PermGen space error and the site stops responding. 
Should I increase the memory still some more? Is there anything else that I can do to from the tomcat side so that it does not run into the PermGen space issue?
Thanks in advance for pointers/tips etc.

Answer (score 4):

The `-Xmx` option only affects the available heap space, and has no effect on the PermGen memory pool.

To increase the permgen pool beyond the 64MB default, use the `-XX:MaxPermSize` options, e.g.

`-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

This is a [Sun Hotspot VM-specific option](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp), and likely won't work on other JVMs.

Answer (score 0):

This should help 
http://frankkieviet.blogspot.co.uk/2006/10/how-to-fix-dreaded-permgen-space.html